# Predict option IV volatility when I have stock price and previous and next day price

Tags: options, implied-volatility

If I have data for IV for the previous day the next da and the stock price in intraday format , can i calculate the option price in intrday format?

Comment: I think there is a conceptual error: you cannot "predict" implied volatility since it's **implied** in option prices. That means that **IV is a result of demand-and-supply of options** and it can be driven by a big number of factors, not just the underlying.

From the theoretical point of view tho, the IV is the root-mean-square deviation of the underlying over the life of the option (that is from underwriting to expiration) **expected by market participants**, so you can estimate a model for the instantaneous variance of the process and forecast with it; EWMA and GARCH are often preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Given 3 days of stock prices, you could calculate two days of return and hence calculate the annualized historical volatility which would be the close estimate of the implied volatility. However, more data points would give a better picture of the true implied vol of this stock.